# Problem on $L^{\infty} $ space

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $L^{\infty}(X,\cal{S},\mu)$ is a normed linear space provided $f\equiv g$ iff $f=g$ a.e

---

we know that $\|f\|_{\infty}=\inf\{M\ge 0: M $ is  an essential bound of $f\}$ where $f$ on $X$ said to be an essential bounded function if there is a non-negative real number $M$ such that $\mu\left(\{x\in X|f(x)|>M\}\right)=0$
Now for proving NLS

i) $\|f\|_{\infty} =0 \,$ iff  $\,|f|=0$

ii) $\|\lambda f\|_{\infty}=|\lambda |\|f\|_{\infty}$

iii) $\|f + g\|_{\infty} \le \|f\|_{\infty} +\|g\|_{\infty} $

Proving (ii) is easy but what about (i) & (iii) and where i use the provided part ???

Comment: Hint: If $f \in L^{\infty}$, then there is a measurable set $E$ so that $\sup \{|f(x)| \, \mid \, x \in E\} = \|f\|_{\infty}$ and $\mu(X \setminus E) = 0$.  Hence, up to a set of measure zero, $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is simply the usual sup-norm.

Comment: But where i have to use $f\equiv g $ iff $f=g$  a.e